# R- adding p-value and tau to plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a scatter plot with a Loess curve using the following code. I ran the MannKendall test on this data and want to display the tau and p-value on the graph.

```
ggplot(LITTLEC.S, aes(Date, TP)) + 
  geom_point(color="light sea green", size = 4, alpha = 1/2) + 
  ggtitle("Little Carnelian Lake Total Phosphorus") + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess") + 
  ylab("TP, mg/L") + theme_bw()

MannKendall(LITTLE.C$TP)
```

Comment: how do you want to display the tau and p-value? can you provide some sample data, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: just use `geom_annotate`

Comment: rather `annotate(geom = "text", ...)`.

Comment: Per @Gregor, see [this help page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/annotate.html) for details.